# How to add a dropdown into telerik grid for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a requirement to implement this telerik grid in my application(You can check the grid demo here:- [GRID](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom) ). I want one of the column in the grid to be a dropdown control, which displays all the values on click of it.

I followed few articles available on telerik site([Article1](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates)), but still I could not get the functionality implemented.

Basically, I am getting data for the dropdown from DB and saving it into a viewstate, in the controller. Which I later Bind it to the editor template(of dropdown).

I have shared my code for your reference. Please let me know if you any suggestions.

Here is my source code:- 
1. Grid's source code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Lamp.Model.RemedyOrHpnaCaseModel>()
.Name("Grid")
 .EnableCustomBinding(true)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.SystemName).Width("20%");
    columns.Bound(p => p.PartNumber).Width("20%");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Manufacturer).Width("20%");
    columns.Bound(p => p.CasePartNumber).Width("20%");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Notes).Title("Notes");
    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create();
    toolbar.Save();
})
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Pageable()
.Navigatable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:460px" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .PageSize(10)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.PartNumber);
        model.Field(p => p.PartNumber).Editable(false);
        model.Field(p => p.SystemName).Editable(false);
        model.Field(p => p.Manufacturer).Editable(false);          

    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("RemedyOrHpnaCase_Read", "LCMLookup"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("RemedyOrHpnaCase_Update", "LCMLookup"))
)
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)
```

2. Source Code of the editor template(for DropDown)

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList<Lamp.Model.CasePartNumber>()
       .Name("CasePartNumber") // Name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property
           .DataValueField("DeviceID") // The value of the dropdown is taken from the CasePartID property
           .DataTextField("PartNumber") // The text of the items is taken from the CasePartName property
       .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["CasePartNumber"]) // A list of all casepartnumber which is populated in the controller
   ```

   )

3.Source code of the controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RemedyOrHpnaCase()
    {
        LCMLookupDAO lcmLookupDAO = new LCMLookupDAO();            
        ViewData["CasePartNumber"] = lcmLookupDAO.PopulateCasePartNumber();

        return View("RemedyOrHpnaCase", model);
    }
```

4. Source code of Model class

   ```
   public class RemedyOrHpnaCaseModel
   {

       public string SystemName { get; set; }
       public string PartNumber { get; set; }
       public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
       [UIHint("CasePartNumberEditor")]
       public IEnumerable CasePartNumber { get; set; }
       public string Notes { get; set; }

   }
   ```

   public class CasePartNumber
   {
       public int? DeviceID { get; set; }
       public string PartNumber { get; set; }
   }

Comment: see this article http://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-dropdown-list-to-a-grid-column

Comment: @Feras- Thanks for sharing. I checked this article, but it is for adding dropdown in kendo ui grid. I wanted to add drop down in the telerik grid for mvc.